# Library for Distibuted Java Communication with RMI

Tags: java, rmi, distributed

I am trying to solve the age old problem of interprocess comms, specifically for a client server model where the client is GUI.

I have looked at Chronicle and although it can serialize objects, it lacks in the features of RMI.  It can pass POJO's but cannot run methods.  Rather than blend the two or not use RMI at all and write a protocol to handle Chronicle comms to implement method calls I am looking for the modern alternatives.

Looking around Cajo seems to be a good fit, however it seems little active development is happening.

Then again Akka also seems to fit the bill but I cannot find much comparison between the two on the net.

What library is a good fit for the problem, and will be supported well into the future?

EDIT:

After refrencing the docs and comments here I have more questions.

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t101131.html?start=15

Is Cajo obsolete now due to updates in RMI or is it still an easier to use alternative?

Comment: Why do you need method calls and POJOs specifically? Why won't a good ole, say, JSON or protobuf interchange work? Doing RMI makes your protocol non portable, which is rather sad given we are talking about Java

Comment: Because then a protocol layer is needed, which is unnecessary since I don't need it to be language portable, and I want it to be simple.

Comment: No protocol layer is needed at all, that's a myth; you can use either of them without having to do HTTP

Comment: Without organizing JSON data, how would you tell the server from the client to do something? The structure of the JSON will be dependent on how the object is designed.  It adds an unnecessary layer of complexity the way I see it.

Comment: That stands true for RMI too; information about methods to invoke, POJOs to handle etc has to come from somewhere! Anyway, your choice...

Comment: What commands does your game need to send between client and server? Don't look at frameworks before you know that. Then pick the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your distributed processes are `Java` then why don't you want to use `RMI`? In any case what do you mean by modern? `RMI` is fast since it is just above the `TCP` sockets and `EJB` containers are based on it. Akka is for non-blocking I/O which is fast but is not the same topic as your OP.

Comment: Ok I see your point on Akka. But Cajo does RMI and makes it a bit easier, right?

Comment: If you don't have *any* performance requirements **and** you believe that the library is stable **and** supported **and** there is no learning curve **and** you will be able to code faster, then IMO only then should you opt for one over `RMI`

Comment: I'm not saying that you cannot do async IO in Akka, because that's definitely possible, but if you think that's "it" about Akka, then you're missing 95% of it: http://akka.io/